# regular expression for dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm

Tags: regex, validation, date

I want to check date in `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format, now I am using

```
/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\-(19|20)\d{2}$/
```

regular expression to match date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format

But I want to check the `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format.
Can anyone modify this regular expression for `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format?

Comment: Date example = 22-12-2013 21:30

Comment: from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("2014","%Y")

Comment: I want to check input type 22-12-2013 21:30 to validate if format is not dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm like I am using var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\-(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
  if(!(date_regex.test(dateval)))
  {                                                                                                                                        to test dateval format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Do You want allow 1-12-2010 like date?
I will do that RegExp but I need to know if You want 01 or 1 is allowed too

Comment: In which language? In what format do you have your date? (Is it a string, some DateTime type) If you want good help, invest some time into your question and please add relevant code to your question and don't put it into a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a Regexp for such date format.
But be aware that it accepts both dates **1-12-2011 19:20** and **01-12-2011 19:20.**

```
^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])-\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$
```

Comment: This won't work with date string with incorrect hour and minutes, for example '01-02-2016 28:61', I have posted the one which worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Regular Expression for date format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm

```
^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\-\d\d\d\d\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

Javascript example:
`/^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\-\d\d\d\d\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/.test('12/12/2017 12:45')` returns true

`/^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\-\d\d\d\d\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/.test('12/12/2017 12:65')`  returns false

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Comment: @ankitsuthar, The answer marked as correct is not working for me, please try with an example like '01-02-2016 28:61' (note that hour and minute is incorrect) The regex marked as correct will return true for this which is incorrect. You may use https://regex101.com/ to try it

Comment: When I paste the example into my console it returns false :(

Answer (score 3):

Given that dates are *irregular* (with varying numbers of days in each month depending on month, year and century, they're not really well suited to regular expressions, at least for checking validity.

For example, the regular expression to ensure you don't get February 30, or February 29 (unless the year is a multiple of 4 and not a multiple of 100 unless it's *also* a multiple of 400) will be truly horrendous.

I'd suggest just using a very simple regex to check the *formatting,* something like:

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

and then extracting the individual fields for separate *validity* checks in code.

Regular expressions are a powerful tool but, like any tool, you have to know when to (and when *not* to) use them. That's the sign of a true toolsmith.

In any case, that regex of yours suffers from a Y2.1K problem. The instant you hit 2100, it'll stop working. And don't think you've got plenty of time, we thought that as well for Y2K :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident it will always be `dd` rather than `d` and so forth (`mm` vs `m`) then you can use:

`/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/`

If, however, you're not confident it will always be `dd`, but might instead just be `d`, I suggest:

`/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2,4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}/`

I've left the minutes as `\d{2}` because I don't ever see 1:05 PM written as 1:5.

Of course, this will just verify it fits the right format more or less - this will not check for crazy dates, like "February 99."  Considering deleting this answer as others are better.

Comment: This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string.           when i tested /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/ expression in http://regex101.com/ then i get the above information can you solve it

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(19|20)\d{2}\s+(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\:(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])$/
```

Check [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#/%5E%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5Cd%7C3%5B01%5D%29-%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5Cd%7C3%5B01%5D%29-%2819%7C20%29%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cs+%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%5C%3a%280%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B1-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%24/) for an explanation :)

Comment: can you give me the date example on which you test this regular expression

Comment: Your second capturing group should be `(0[1-9]|1[012])` to reflect months. In some regional areas both `00:00` and `24:00` are valid times

Comment: stema: good point - updating my answer; Jan: in some areas even 26:00 is a valid time expression, but we should think of OP's use case, not all probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that matches your format *exactly*, bear in mind that days and months cannot be 00, hours cannot be 24, and minutes/seconds cannot be 60.

[/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4} ([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2}/gm](https://regexper.com/#%2F%280%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B12%5D%5Cd%7C3%5B01%5D%29-%280%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D%29-%5Cd%7B4%7D%20%28%5B01%5D%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%28%3A%5B0-5%5D%5Cd%29%7B2%7D%2Fgm)

As a side-note, this can be used regardless of position in order to parse a date from larger strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the validation I have been using:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](202[0-9])[ ](0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])[:](0[0-9]|[12345][0-9])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$value = "22-12-2013 21:30";

if($value=~m/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/){
   print "Matched\n";
}
else{
   print "Not matched...";
}
```

Comment: 99-99-9999 99:99 is not really an appropriate date