# Counting date occurrences in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, counter

I'm currently trying to count the number of times a date occurs within a chat log for example the file I'm reading from may look something like this:

```
*username* (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss): *message here*
```

However I need to split the date from the time as I currently treat them as one. Im currently struggling to solve my problem so any help is appreciated. Down below is some sample code that I'm currently using to try get the date count working. Im currently using a counter however I'm wondering if there are other ways to count dates.

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt") ,))
mtxtr = filename.read()
date = []
number = []
occurences =  Counter(date)
mtxtformat = mtxtr.split("\r\n")
print 'The Dates in the chat are as follows'
print "--------------------------------------------"
for mtxtf in mtxtformat:
    participant = mtxtf.split("(")[0]
    date = mtxtf.split("(")[-1]
    message = date.split(")")[0]
    date.append(date1.strip())
for item in date:
    if item not in number:
        number.append(item)
for item in number:        
    occurences =  date.count(item)
    print("Date Occurences " + " is: " + str(occurences))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360599/regular-expression-for-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use regex and take the count of the date pattern you have in the log file. It would be faster too.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date and time are going to be enclosed in parentheses at the start of the message (i.e. no parentheses `(...):` will be seen before the one containing the date and time):

`*username* (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss): *message here*`

Then you can extract based on the parens:

```
import re

...

parens = re.compile(r'\((.+)\)')
for mtxtf in mtxtformat:
    match = parens.search(mtxtf)
    date.append(match.group(1).split(' ')[0])

...
```

Note: If the message itself contains parens, this may match more than just the needed (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss). Doing `match.group(1).split(' ')[0]` would still give you the information you are looking for assuming there is no information enclosed in parens before your date-time information (for the current line).

Note2: Ideally enclose this in a try-except to continue on to the next line if the current line doesn't contain useful information.